# Using predicate to find strings that start with a specific letter (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, generics, predicate

I'm quite new to using predicates for finding something specific within a collection.
Here's my example:

```
static void FindPersons(string firstLetter)
        {
            List<string> names = new List<string>()
        {"Marcus", "John", "Jesse", "Lance", "Aaron", "Archibald", "Victor"
        };



            List<string> names2 = names.FindAll(a => a.StartsWith(firstLetter));

            foreach (var name in names2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name);
            }
        }
```

I'd call the method within Main:

```
FindPersons("a");
```

I had to use string for the first letter because StartsWith takes string as a parameter (or I could use char and ToString().

How can I do this using this shorter syntax?
One more question - Generally, how often during your work you use predicates to find specific objects within a collection? 
Thanks.

Comment: _What_ is your question? Instead of `List.FindAll` you can use `names.Where(n => n.StartsWith(firstLetter))`. However, that doesn't make a great difference. Your second question is just opinion-based.

Comment: Nit pick: `FindPersons` should return the list. `PrintPeople` should write to console..

Comment: `names.FindAll(a => a.StartsWith(firstLetter)).ForEach(Console.WriteLine);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Console.WriteLine(string.Join<string>("\n", result));` as following method to do that.

```
    static void FindPersons(string firstLetter)
    {
        List<string> names = new List<string>()
        {"Marcus", "John", "Jesse", "Lance", "Aaron", "Archibald", "Victor"
        };

        List<string> result = names.Where(a => a.StartsWith(firstLetter, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join<string>("\n", result));

    }
```